# difference in ggplot scaling with log transformation

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have  the following skewed data:

```
set.seed(3)
x <- rgamma(1e6, 0.1, .2)

summary(log(x))
#     Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
# -170.637  -12.760   -5.825   -8.828   -1.745    3.807
```

Looked at the log-transformed distribution of the data

```
summary(log(x))
#     Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
# -170.637  -12.760   -5.825   -8.828   -1.745    3.807
```

Visualizing the data with transformation:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x), aes(x)) + 
  geom_histogram(bins = 100) + 
  scale_x_continuous(trans = "log")
```

[image]

What is the reason for the difference in the log transformation and scaling in ggplot? I see there are differences by having a look at x-axis. The minimum value in the summary is `-170.637` while the plot has values in the range `5.8e-62`.

update:

```
g1 <- ggplot(data.frame(x), aes(x)) + geom_histogram(bins = 100)
g2 <- ggplot(data.frame(x), aes(x)) + geom_histogram(bins = 100) + scale_x_continuous(trans = "log")
g3 <- ggplot(data.frame(x), aes(log(x))) + geom_histogram(bins = 100)
gridExtra::grid.arrange(g1, g2, g3, ncol=3)
```

[image]

```
g1 <- ggplot(data.frame(x), aes(x)) + geom_histogram(bins = 100)
g2 <- ggplot(data.frame(x), aes(x)) + geom_histogram(bins = 100) + scale_x_log10()
g3 <- ggplot(data.frame(x), aes(log10(x))) + geom_histogram(bins = 100)
gridExtra::grid.arrange(g1, g2, g3, ncol=3)
```

[image]

Comment: FYI, the default breaks of the log transformation is done by the `scales::log_breaks` function, which I found informative to look at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be easier to see if you instead use `scale_x_log10`

```
ggplot(data.frame(x), aes(x)) + 
  geom_histogram(bins = 100) + 
  scale_x_log10()
```

gives

[image]

Then, we can do a few things to compare. First, we can change the labels:

```
myBreaks <-
  10^c(-61, -43, -25, -7)

ggplot(data.frame(x), aes(x)) + 
  geom_histogram(bins = 100) + 
  scale_x_log10(breaks = myBreaks
                , labels = log10(myBreaks))
```

gives

[image]

We can also get the same plot by transforming `x` before plotting it:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = log10(x)), aes(x)) + 
  geom_histogram(bins = 100)
```

gives

[image]

and, we can compare all of these to the summary for the `log10(x)`

```
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
-74.1065  -5.5416  -2.5300  -3.8340  -0.7579   1.6531
```

See how that matches up with the graphs above pretty closely?

`scale_x_log10` and `scale_x_continuous(trans = "log")` are not actually changing the data -- they are changing the scaling of the axis, but leaving the labels in the original units.

Bringing it back to your original values, `log(5.8e-62)` is `-141` -- which is the value you would expect to see if the plot was of the converted data.

If you really must have the log-values displayed, you can also accomplish that within the mapping, with the added advantage that the axis-label defaults to a meaningful value as well:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = x), aes(log10(x))) + 
  geom_histogram(bins = 100)
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Thanks (+1) for  "..are not actually changing the data". Could you comment on how to convert `x` other than `log(x)` and plot the labels automatically based on the data?

Comment: The simplest response is "Why?" In general, it will be easier to read your graphs if they are plotted in the measured units, rather than log-transformed (this is especially true for log-base-e, which is non-trivial to convert in your head, as evidenced by the fact that you didn't immediately recognize that `5.8e-62` was the same as `e^-141`). If there is a good reason to convert, convert before plotting (e.g., with `log(x)` as in the last two plots in my edited answer).

Comment: @Prradep, see the edit for an alternative way to accomplish the transformation before plotting.

Comment: Thanks..but I have to plot with original data and then plot the transformed data. So `ggplot(data.frame(x = x), aes(log10(x)))` does not work for me.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by this comment, or why it prevents that solution from working. Do you mean you need one plot with `x` and one plot with `log10(x)`? I so, why would this not work? Or do you mean you need to plot `log10(x)~x`? You can do that with `aes(x = x, y = log10(x))`. Or do you need each for different layers? Then try `ggplot(data.frame(x = x)) + geom_histogram(aes(log10(x)) + geom_histogram(aes(x))`.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by this comment, or why it prevents that solution from working. Do you mean you need one plot with `x` and one plot with `log10(x)`? I so, why would this not work? Or do you mean you need to plot `log10(x)~x`? You can do that with `aes(x = x, y = log10(x))`. Or do you need each for different layers? Then try `ggplot(data.frame(x = x)) + geom_histogram(aes(log10(x)) + geom_histogram(aes(x))`.

Comment: Sorry, I have `g1 <- ggplot(data.frame(x), aes(x)) + geom_histogram(bins = 100)`; Now I need to modify the plotted data using log transformation i.e., `g1 + ...` I need to add on top of my basic plot. Are there any ways to acheive this including the necessary labels? Atleast, I would not the `myBreaks` in advance.

Comment: The question, again, is why you are unable to change this (and why you are unhappy with labeling in the original units). However, you can change the default data of a `ggplot` object using the `%+%` operator, e.g. `g1 %+% data.frame(x = log10(x))` should do what you want here.